# Aligning flex items to the right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container and inside there are 3 boxes: yellow, green and red.

I gave `display:flex` to the container and gave `justify-content:flex-start` for the items to start at beginning.

I wanted to move the red box to the end so I gave `margin-right: auto` to the yellow box so that the red box could move to end (not sure if this is the exact way to move the red box to end, if not i want help in that too).

**So the question is:** I want the green box in the vertical middle of the container and I want to move it to the extreme right like the red box (but should be in the middle of container)

How do I do it with flex box?

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: royalblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.yellowbox {
  color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.greenbox {
  color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.redbox {
  color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="yellowbox">
    <p>the white text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="greenbox">
    <p>the black text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="redbox">
    <p>the red text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

THIS IS MY CODEPEN LINK: http://codepen.io/ShamZ/pen/pRLELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may increase some of the `margin`s but you must allow the `flex` children to `wrap`. and use `order` to put the green box in last position

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 50%),linear-gradient(to top,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 50%);
  background-color: royalblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.yellowbox {
  color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-right: 50%;
}
.greenbox {
  order:1;
  color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: -100px 0 auto auto;
}
.redbox {
  margin:0 0 0 auto;
  color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="yellowbox">
    <p>the white text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="greenbox">
    <p>the black text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="redbox">
    <p>the red text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Qdmpbb